# is safe to use unique token via get?

Tags: php, mysql, file

I need to manage *user folders* separately, this is my database structure:

**users** {user_id, username, password, token}

**user_folders** {user_folder_id, user_id, folder_name}

I'm using a file manager where I can set the home directory, but I prefer not to use login to display the folders because the file manager is an iframe inside another website where the user is *already* logged in, I thought to pass in a single identification (*token*) for each user by get method, then the file manager just would pull files that user ..

ps.: a new random token is generated every time.

my question is: **what kinds of security flaws can exist**? is it safe to pass a token to authenticate and display folders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In security its a bad idea to "roll your own."  The problem you are trying to solve has already been solved before and good tool to do is `hash_hmac` which is built into php.

Your security flaw is trying to "roll your own"

Comment: I'm not trying to build my own hash generator, the point is: is it safe the way I'm using them? passing by get to authenticate and display folders?

Comment: POST or GET it doesn't matter. If you are worried about mitm attacks, then you should be using SSL/https. If you are worried about people guessing/stealing, using CSRF to get the token, then the issue is about about proper hasihng, CSRF tokens, etc...

Comment: I'll hash a salt, username and password with `hash_hmac` it will be safe?

Comment: To do that it would seem you need a cleartext version of the users password stored somewhere (session?) so that would not be a good idea.

Comment: What about username and salt?

Comment: you mean use the user's name salted and hashed as the `$data` option of `hash_hmac` i think that would be reasonably safe for many applications.